# Переключение между пунктами меню при скролле

Tags: bootstrap, прокрутка, menu

Есть bootstrap меню http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/navbar-fixed-on-scrolling-with-transition
Как сделать, чтобы при скролле, помимо появления background, происходило плавное переключение между активными пунктами верхнего фиксированного меню?